# Bash: Changing date of a file name and increment number at end

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a short script that will check if the file in question has today's date prefixed (if not, add it) and increment the version number at the end. I have succeeded in doing the date part.

I'm struggling with trying to increment the number at the end, especially because a) I want it to apply to different file types (e.g. PDF, and .md) and b) I'm not starting from 0/1 so I want it to continue from where the numbers already are, e.g 20.

A filename might be something like `2023-09-12 Name V.32.md`

With this script, I've achieved the first part of the date replacing:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName="$1"
f10="${fileName:0:10}"
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")

if  [[  $f10 != "$today" ]]; then # if the first 10 characters are NOT the same as today's date, then

       cp "$fileName" "$today ${fileName:11}" # copy the file with today's date
        
fi
```

i.e. `2023-09-12 Name V.32.md` turns into `2023-09-13 Name V.32.md`

However, sometimes I start multiple `V`ersions in the same day, so I want this to also work that whenever the script is triggered, the newly created file gets a new number, so that the goal is to turn `2023-09-12 Name V.32.md` into `2023-09-13 Name V.33.md`

changing both the date and the number.

How can I do this?

thanks

## **Edit**

So I've added @treuss's suggestion, so it looks like this now:

```
fileName="$1"
f10="${fileName:0:10}"
newName=${i:11}
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
year=$(date +"%Y")
month=$(date +"%m")

fileNameWithoutExt="${fileName%.*}"
fileNameExt="${fileName##*.}"
lastPartOfFileName="${fileNameWithoutExt##*[^0-9]}"
firstPartOfFileName="${fileNameWithoutExt%$lastPartOfFileName}" 
fileNameNew="${firstPartOfFileName}$((lastPartOfFileName + 1)).${fileNameExt}"


case $f10 in

       ($today) cp "$fileName" "$fileNameNew" ;;
       

       (*) cp "$fileName" "$today ${fileNameNew:11}" ;;

esac
```

Essentially, this works. It renames
`2023-09-12 Name V.32.md` into `2023-09-13 Name V.32.md`
which is great. And I can turn
`2023-09-13 Name V.32.md` into `2023-09-13 Name V.33.md`

However, combinations don't work as desired. Like, if these files exist

```
2023-09-12 Name V.32.md
2023-09-13 Name V.33.md
```

and I try using the script on `2023-09-12 Name V.32.md` it replaces the second file there instead of incrementing the number at the end.

How can I always have it increment the number at the end so that it never replaces a file but just adds a number?

## Solution:

I posted the solution I wanted to reach in the other thread: [Bash: check if number in filename exists, if so increment, regardless of rest of filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77104365/15999132)

Comment: Additional to the answer you've already got, take a look at bash's built-in regex support; `[[ $fileName =~ $regex ]]` will populate `BASH_REMATCH` with match groups from that regex, from which you can then generate a new / destination name.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy where would I put `[[ $fileName =~ $regex ]]`? I'm still pretty new at bash.

Comment: Is there an advantage of using regex over what I have now?

Comment: Terseness, generally. And error handling; a regex match makes it easy to say "nope, it doesn't match, this logic won't work" instead of maybe doing something wrong and generating corrupt output. BTW, answers don't belong in questions; if I were following the letter of [meta] consensus I'd be obliged to edit it back out. (Follow-up questions, by contrast, are by that consensus _separate questions_ and should be asked as such).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure, if this is the best way, but a lot can be done with the # and % operators of parameter expansion. Here is some example (based on your input filename):

```
filename="2023-09-12 Name V.32.md"
filenameWithoutExt="${filename%.*}"                              # 2023-09-12 Name V.32
filenameExt="${filename##*.}"                                    # md
lastPartOfFilename="${filenameWithoutExt##*[^0-9]}"              # 32
firstPartOfFilename="${filenameWithoutExt%$lastPartOfFilename}"  # 2023-09-12 Name V.
filenameNew="${firstPartOfFilename}$((lastPartOfFilename + 1)).${filenameExt}"
# 2023-09-12 Name V.33.md
```

This is missing any checks, e.g. if the last part of the filename is indeed numeric. You need to add those if you want to make your script robust.

Edit: To answer your additional question, if you want to avoid overwriting files, just keep increasing the number until you find a filename that does not exist:

```
num=$((lastPartOfFilename + 1))
filenameNew="${firstPartOfFilename}${num}.${filenameExt}"
while [ -f $filenameNew ]; do
        num=$((num + 1))
        filenameNew="${firstPartOfFilename}${num}.${filenameExt}"
done
```

Comment: OK, thanks! I've added an edit in the post and some questions and problems.

Comment: That looks good, but I don't understand where to add the new while loop. Sorry, I'm still pretty new to bash.