# Bash: check if number in filename exists, if so increment, regardless of rest of filename?

Tags: bash

I'm struggling with a problem that I asked here: [Bash: Changing date of a file name and increment number at end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097755/bash-changing-date-of-a-file-name-and-increment-number-at-end?noredirect=1#comment135920238_77097755)

I'm trying to create a shell/bash script that increments a filename (regardless of its type) so that `2023-09-12 Name V.32.md` is checked if the first 10 digits equal today's date; if not, the date is corrected. But regardless of the date, the version number at the end gets incremented to the next number, e.g.
`2023-09-12 Name V.32.md` gets turned into `2023-09-14 Name V.33.md`

I've figured out the date change, but the version numbers are giving me trouble, as I want these to change whenever I trigger the script on a file.

Also important, is that I do NOT want it to ever overwrite a file, which is currently happening. It should instead create a copy of whatever file and increment the number to the next available number, so that if these files exist:

```
2023-09-12 Name V.32.md
2023-09-14 Name V.33.md
```

and I point the script at the first file it doesn't replace the second but instead creates a new copy that's called `2023-09-14 Name V.34.md`

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName="$1"
f10="${fileName:0:10}"

today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")


fileNameWithoutExt="${fileName%.*}"                                          # 2023-09-12 Name V.32
fileNameExt="${fileName##*.}"                                                # md
lastPartOfFileName="${fileNameWithoutExt##*[^0-9]}"   
num=$((lastPartOfFileName + 1))                                              # 32
firstPartOfFileName="${fileNameWithoutExt%$num}"                             # 2023-09-12 Name V.
fileNameNew="${firstPartOfFileName}${num}.${fileNameExt}"                    # 2023-09-12 Name V. 33.md


if [[ -f "$fileName" ]]; then

    if [[ $f10 = $today ]]; then

            #    num=$((num + 1))

                cp "$fileName" "$fileNameNew" 


    elif [[ $f10 != $today ]]; then


        cp "$fileName" "$today ${fileNameNew:11}" 

    fi     
fi
```

This script if run on `2023-09-12 Name V.32.md` will create `2023-09-12 Name V.3233.md` but I can't figure out how to remove that double numbering. Also, it's still replacing the file and not creating a new one.

Thanks!

## Edit

For clarification the format of the filename is `[date] [specific name, e.g. Presentation] [Version number, e.g. V32].[extension, e.g. .md or .pdf]`

Comment: You only gave an **example** of sucha a file name. Define the general format for it!

Comment: @user1934428 added clarification, is that what you meant?

Comment: Your own solution should be added as a separate answer, not edited into the question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question on [meta].

Comment: BTW, note that any answer to this that doesn't go out of its way to implement locking will be prone to race conditions if there's more than one copy of the script running at the same time.

Comment: How can the specific name look like? For instance, would `xy-z V51.abc` a valid specific name, so that you could have a file `1956-12-31 xy-z V51.abc V32.pdf`?

Comment: I still don't know what you're asking sorry. A specific name would look like `2023-09-12 Name V.32.md` with the date, name and version number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of bash's regular expression support and do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName=$1

if [[ $fileName =~ ([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)(.*)([0-9]+)\.([^.]*) ]]; then
  # BASH_REMATCH match groups:
  # 1 - date
  # 2 - everything else
  # 3 - number
  # 4 - extension

  number=$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} + 1 ))

  while :; do
    newFileName="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${number}.${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    [[ -f $newFileName ]] || break
    let number++
  done

  echo "copy $fileName to $newFileName"
  cp "$fileName" "$newFileName"
else
  echo "ERROR: invalid filename" >&2
fi
```

If we have the above script in `renumber.sh` and there is a file named `2023-09-12 Name V.32.md` in the current directory, we see the following behavior:

```
$ ls
'2023-09-12 Name V.32.md'   renumber.sh
$ sh renumber.sh 2023-09-12\ Name\ V.32.md
copy 2023-09-12 Name V.32.md to 2023-09-14 Name V.33.md
$ ls
'2023-09-12 Name V.32.md'  '2023-09-14 Name V.33.md'   renumber.sh
$ sh renumber.sh 2023-09-14\ Name\ V.33.md
copy 2023-09-14 Name V.33.md to 2023-09-14 Name V.34.md
$ ls
'2023-09-12 Name V.32.md'  '2023-09-14 Name V.33.md'  '2023-09-14 Name V.34.md'   renumber.sh
```

Comment: That works, but that has the same problem as I was having,  i.e. that if I then run the script on V.32 again, it just overwrites V.33 again instead of creating a new version. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, just check if the target filename exists and keep incrementing `$number` until it doesn't. That's just a simple loop; I've updated the answer.

Comment: Now it's perfect. I'll add my updated version in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bash regular expression apart, if you use prefix/suffix tricks, you can use `set -x` to display what bash is doing.

In your case, if you run your script with `set -x` (after the shebang or in the shebang, eg: `#!/bin/bash -x`), this will output this:

```bash
+ declare num=33
+ declare 'firstPartOfFileName=2023-09-12 Name V.32'
declare firstPartOfFileName="${fileNameWithoutExt%$num}"
```

The error is due to your num being incremented first, so `${fileNameWithoutExt%$num}` don't produce the expected result.

You have to use the value before:

```bash
declare firstPartOfFileName="${fileNameWithoutExt%"$lastPartOfFileName"}"            # 2023-09-12 Name V.
```

Also, you don't need to test for `!=` if you already test `==`:

```bash
if [[ "$f10" == "$today" ]]; then
  ...
else 
  # f10 is NOT equal to today
  ...
fi
```

Comment: Could you explain how exactly to use that `+ declare` thing here? I don't understand that and it seems that that would be hardcoding that number as the first to use, no? Because what if I want to use the script to change the name of a different file group that has a number not 33?

Comment: You don't use it: this was the result of `set -x` which simply echo the command as it is being evaluated. The + indicate the depth in case of subprocess. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-set (and '-x')